# Frequency counts in R

Tags: r, frequency, reshape

This may seem like a very basic R question, but I'd appreciate an answer. I have a data frame in the form of:

```
col1    col2
a   g
a   h
a   g
b   i
b   g
b   h
c   i
```

I want to transform it into counts, so the outcome would be like this. I've tried using table () function, but seem to only be able to get the count for one column.

```
    a   b   c
g   2   1   0
h   1   1   0
i   0   1   1
```

How do I do it in R?

Comment: Do you tried this: `table(df$column1, df$column2)`

Comment: This should be put on-hold under *Unclear what you're asking* until you add what code you tried and possibly more details surrounding the structure of your data.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not really sure what you used, but `table` works fine for me!

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c"), 
                     V2 = c("g", "h", "g", "i", "g", "h", "i")), 
                .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -7L))
table(df)
#    V2
# V1  g h i
#   a 2 1 0
#   b 1 1 1
#   c 0 0 1
```

Notes:

- Try `table(df[c(2, 1)])` (or `table(df$V2, df$V1)`) to swap the rows and columns.
- Use `as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))` to get a `data.frame` as your output. (`as.data.frame` will create a long `data.frame`, not one in the same output format you desire).

Comment: Or `table(df$V1, df$V2)`

Comment: @csgillespie, but I like that when you use `table` directly, you get additional labels from the variable names. You can get the same with your approach by specifying the desired names (eg: `table(V1 = df$V1, V2 = df$V2)`) but I like to save the typing when I can :)

Comment: and using `[` you can choose columns programmatically with variables storing columns names.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it was "better", just it was another way. You can imagine a future SO question where "I have two vectors..."

Comment: @AnandaMahto LOL +7 for an answer consisting of `table(df)` when [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18797893/1478381) gets +1 (from me). I really don't get SO voting sometimes.

Comment: @AnandaMahto now it's 2 :-) pretty good answer!

Answer (score 4):

Using `f` from @Ananda you can use `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)

> dcast(f, V1~V2)
Using V2 as value column: use value.var to override.
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
  V1  g  h  i
1 a   2  1  0
2 b   1  1  1
3 c   0  0  1
```

However, I'm writing this only in case you may need something more than just `table` (which for this case it's the simplest correct answer) in the future, like:

```
set.seed(1)
f$var <- rnorm(7)

> f
  V1 V2        var
1 a   g -0.6264538
2 a   h  0.1836433
3 a   g -0.8356286
4 b   i  1.5952808
5 b   g  0.3295078
6 b   h -0.8204684
7 c   i  0.4874291

> dcast(f, V1~V2, value.var="var", fun.aggregate=sum)
  V1          g          h         i
1 a  -1.4620824  0.1836433 0.0000000
2 b   0.3295078 -0.8204684 1.5952808
3 c   0.0000000  0.0000000 0.4874291
```