# From a long format create a frequency table

Tags: r

From a long for dataframe

```
data <- data.frame(samples = c("species1","species2","species1"), sample = c("panda","tiger","tiger"))
```

How can we procude a table of frequencies?

Here an example of expected output.

```
data_st <- data.frame(samples = c("species1","species2"), pande=c(1,0), tiger=c(1,1))


> data_st
>        samples pande tiger
>     1 species1     1     1
>     2 species2     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> table(data)
          sample
samples    panda tiger
  species1     1     1
  species2     0     1
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to have this structure as dataframe and not as table?

Comment: @ElrMant see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18895118/1315767) for you to get a data.frame from `table`'s output